# How to use invert color with semantic-ui piled segment?

Tags: less, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-segment

I'm playing with semantic-ui [piled segment](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/segment.html#piled) but got some trouble when trying to invert color.

#### HTML

```
<div class="ui blue inverted piled segment ">
    <div class="ui items">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="content">
                <blockquote class="description">
                    <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </h3>
                </blockquote>
                <p class="meta">
                    <img class="ui avatar image"
                         src="http://">
                    <b>Édouard</b>, Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

I use the default theme.

#### Current

[image: missing color on semantic-ui inverted piled segment]

This is not the expected behavior as you can still see the sheets below are not blue.

#### Question

- How to use [invert color](http://semantic-ui.com/elements/segment.html#colored) with semantic-ui piled segment?

Comment: I think that calls for either **a)** overriding `.ui.piled.segment:before, .ui.piled.segments:before` and `.ui.piled.segment:after, .ui.piled.segments:after` selectors or **b)** playing with themes (i.e. making one of your own. i think that will lead you to modifying [site.overrides](https://github.com/Semantic-Org/example-github/blob/master/semantic/src/themes/github/elements/segment.overrides) for segments (see [this example from docs](http://semantic-ui.com/usage/theming.html#recreating-github)) and them rebuilding.

Comment: I'd again suggest joining the chat room or project talk for SUI )) You can probably get your answers faster by posting your questions directly or at least providing stackoverflow url to your questions

Comment: @thanks for the help, I consider chat rooms as less accessible areas than SO. I think it's better for the community to capitalize Q&A on SO than on "hidden" space

Comment: that is true, but not in case of SUI. it's not as popular yet as I'd like it to be. I drop by to so sometimes and see questions a week old. usually u'l get a quicker response in that chat room than here. however, you might need to re-post your question sometimes ))